# Swift Twilio Chat iOS 1401 unable to connect to twilio service

Tags: ios, swift3, synchronization, twilio, channel

I successfully integrate `Twilio Cha`t to `Android` and now I'm trying to integrate it to `iOS` using `Swift 3`.

First things to say:

- I followed instructions as frameworks in `Embedded libraires` and `libstdc++` to Linked Libs and run scripts to build phases
- I got a generated and usable token from a server and a SID from an existing channel where identity susbscribed
- The only difference with Android is that my `TwilioChatClientProperties`is just an init one.

So here is my problem: I generate a ChatClient instance using my token, the client connects and I can retrieve SIDs of subscribed channels but when I want to join the one with the SID received that's not succeed and I got the following error

```
error code 1401: Unable to establish connection to Twilio Sync service
```

I checked the client connects but doesn't synchronize

here is my code:

```
let props = TwilioChatClientProperties.init()

TwilioChatClient.chatClient(withToken: token, properties: props, delegate: self ){
        (result, client) -> Void in
              if (result?.isSuccessful())!{ //=> success
                 for channel in (client?.channelsList().subscribedChannels())!{
                     if channel.sid == channel_sid{ 
                         // found
                         channel.join(completion: { (resultJoinChannel) in 
                          // never print anything
                              if(resultJoinChannel?.isSuccessful())!{
                                    print("joined channel")
                              }else{
                                    print("pb joining channel")
                              }
                          })
                      }
                  }
                }
 }
```

I don't know why can I retrieve channels but not join one of them!

After few more effort I'm still at the same level. I would like to add some informations about my logs, here are the last logs when I try to synchronize:

```
2017-05-26 10:52:09.090925+0200 [967:593374] SyncDocument[1]:
    0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.090 | CRITICAL | 38     
   | SyncDocument | request 5 flowId xxx 
    error code 1401: Unable to establish connection to Twilio Sync service
2017-05-26 10:52:09.091380+0200 [967:593374] TNRawHttp[2]:
    0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.091 | WARNING  | 13     
   | TNRawHttp | Could not find any requests for this id: xxx
2017-05-26 10:52:09.091609+0200 [967:593374] SyncDocument[1]:
    0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.091 | CRITICAL | 40     
   | SyncDocument | request 6 flowId xxx 
    error code 1401: Unable to establish connection to Twilio Sync service
2017-05-26 10:52:09.091887+0200 [967:593374] TNRawHttp[2]:
    0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.091 | WARNING  | 13     
| TNRawHttp | Could not find any requests for this id: xxx
2017-05-26 10:52:09.092098+0200 [967:593374] SyncDocument[1]:
    0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.092 | CRITICAL | 42     
   | SyncDocument | request 7 flowId xxx 
    error code 1401: Unable to establish connection to Twilio Sync service
2017-05-26 10:52:09.092704+0200 [967:593374] TNRawHttp[2]:
    0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.092 | WARNING  | 13     
   | TNRawHttp | Could not find any requests for this id: xxx
2017-05-26 10:52:09.093595+0200 [967:593374] SyncDocument[1]:
    0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.093 | CRITICAL | 44     
   | SyncDocument | request 8 flowId xxx 
    error code 1401: Unable to establish connection to Twilio Sync service
2017-05-26 10:52:09.093876+0200 [967:593374] TNRawHttp[2]: 
   0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.093 | WARNING  | 13     
   | TNRawHttp | Could not find any requests for this id: xxx
2017-05-26 10:52:09.094077+0200 [967:593374] SyncDocument[1]: 
   0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.093 | CRITICAL | 46     
   | SyncDocument | request 9 flowId xxx 
    error code 1401: Unable to establish connection to Twilio Sync service
2017-05-26 10:52:09.094368+0200 [967:593374] TNRawHttp[2]: 
   0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.094 | WARNING  | 13     
   | TNRawHttp | Could not find any requests for this id: xxx
2017-05-26 10:52:09.106080+0200 [967:593765] TNHttpTwilsockMessageResult[2]:        
0x16e5f3000 | 05/26/10:52:09.105 | WARNING  | TNHttpTwilsockMessageResult 
   | Could not deliver http request via twilsock: Twilsock has been stopped
2017-05-26 10:52:09.106325+0200 [967:593765] IPM[1]:
    0x16e5f3000 | 05/26/10:52:09.106 | CRITICAL 
    | IPM | public channel request request failed for CHxxxx
2017-05-26 10:52:09.106867+0200 [967:593765] TNRegNotificationCtxSession[2]:
    0x16e5f3000 | 05/26/10:52:09.106 | WARNING  | 19     | TNRegNotificationCtxSession 
    | Could not operate with notification context in twilsock. Error 9
2017-05-26 10:52:09.109605+0200 [967:593766] TNWebsocket[1]:
    0x16e67f000 | 05/26/10:52:09.109 | CRITICAL | 4      
    | TNWebsocket 
    | Received error while waiting for message: Exception: Bad socket descriptor
2017-05-26 10:52:09.110852+0200 [967:593765] TNFinalState[2]:
    0x16e5f3000 | 05/26/10:52:09.110 | WARNING  | 49     
    | TNFinalState | Unexpected event: Error
   0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.111 | INFO
    | 35     | SyncMap | destructed
   0x1aec7cb40 | 05/26/10:52:09.111 | INFO
    | 29     | SyncList | destructed
   0x16e5f3000 | 05/26/10:52:09.111 | INFO
    | 1      | TNTwilsockClient | onDisconnectedImpl >> Final state
   0x16e5f3000 | 05/26/10:52:09.112 | WARNING
    | 49     | TNFinalState | Unexpected event: Disconnected
   0x16e5f3000 | 05/26/10:52:09.112 | DEBUG
    | 1      | TNTwilsockClient | ~TNTwilsockClient - begin
   0x16e5f3000 | 05/26/10:52:09.113 | DEBUG
    | 1      | TNTwilsockClient | Cleaning observers list - begin
   0x16e5f3000 | 05/26/10:52:09.113 | DEBUG
    | 1      | TNTwilsockClient | Cleaning observers list - end
   0x16e5f3000 | 05/26/10:52:09.114 | DEBUG
    | 1      | TNTwilsockClient | ~TNTwilsockClient - end
   0x16e2ab000 | 05/26/10:52:09.616 | DEBUG
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Sending subscription request for action: establish
   0x16e2ab000 | 05/26/10:52:09.616 | INFO
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | trying to send request to: https://cds.us1.twilio.com/v4/Subscriptions
   0x16e2ab000 | 05/26/10:52:09.616 | CRITICAL
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | Http transport has been shut down
   0x16e2ab000 | 05/26/10:52:09.616 | WARNING
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Error while persisting subscriptions: establish
   0x16e2ab000 | 05/26/10:52:14.055 | DEBUG
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Sending subscription request for action: establish
   0x16e2ab000 | 05/26/10:52:14.055 | INFO
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | trying to send request to: https://cds.us1.twilio.com/v4/Subscriptions
   0x16e2ab000 | 05/26/10:52:14.055 | CRITICAL
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | Http transport has been shut down
   0x16e2ab000 | 05/26/10:52:14.056 | WARNING
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Error while persisting subscriptions: establish
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:20.937 | DEBUG
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Sending subscription request for action: establish
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:20.937 | INFO
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | trying to send request to: https://cds.us1.twilio.com/v4/Subscriptions
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:20.937 | CRITICAL
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | Http transport has been shut down
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:20.937 | WARNING
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Error while persisting subscriptions: establish
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:35.238 | DEBUG
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Sending subscription request for action: establish
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:35.238 | INFO
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | trying to send request to: https://cds.us1.twilio.com/v4/Subscriptions
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:35.239 | CRITICAL
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | Http transport has been shut down
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:35.239 | WARNING
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Error while persisting subscriptions: establish
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:51.354 | DEBUG
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Sending subscription request for action: establish
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:51.354 | INFO
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | trying to send request to: https://cds.us1.twilio.com/v4/Subscriptions
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:51.354 | CRITICAL
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | Http transport has been shut down
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:52:51.354 | WARNING
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Error while persisting subscriptions: establish
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:53:25.597 | DEBUG
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Sending subscription request for action: establish
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:53:25.598 | INFO
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | trying to send request to: https://cds.us1.twilio.com/v4/Subscriptions
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:53:25.598 | CRITICAL
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | Http transport has been shut down
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:53:25.598 | WARNING
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Error while persisting subscriptions: establish
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:54:08.247 | DEBUG
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Sending subscription request for action: establish
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:54:08.248 | INFO
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | trying to send request to: https://cds.us1.twilio.com/v4/Subscriptions
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:54:08.248 | CRITICAL
    | 12     | TNHttpTransportClient | Http transport has been shut down
   0x16df63000 | 05/26/10:54:08.248 | WARNING
    | 22     | TSSubscriptions | Error while persisting subscriptions: establish
```

I tried also to leave a channel and to rejoin after, still not working. This is strange to know few things about user and channels but not be able to do actions.

Answer (score 0):

The `subscribedChannels` array for a user will only contain channels they are already a member of.  Is it possible that on your Android client, the identity is already a member of the desired channel but on the iOS client it is a different identity?  Also, it is only necessary to call `join` when first joining a channel, from that point forward the channel will be available to the user once the client initializes.

The best way to find the desired channel, if you already know the channel_sid, would be to use the `channel(withSidOrUniqueName sidOrUniqueName, completion)` method.  Please note that this will not find `private` channels to which the identity has not been invited or added to.

I would recommend trying the following in place of your for loop:

```
chatClient?.channelsList().channel(withSidOrUniqueName: channel_sid) {
    (result, channel) -> Void in
    if (result?.isSuccessful())! {
        if (channel?.status == .joined) {
            print("already joined channel")
        } else {
            channel?.join(completion: { (resultJoinChannel) in
                if (resultJoinChannel?.isSuccessful())! {
                    print("joined channel")
                } else {
                    print("problem joining channel")
                }
            })
        }
    }  else {
        print("problem finding channel")
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I can assist you further!

Thank you,
Randy

Comment: Thanks @rbeiter . I just tried your code, I am right in the `joined` status but I tried `getMessagesCount`and `getUsersCount`and both failed ! I still not understand why can I know state but not params or datas of it

Comment: I am stuck in Programmable chat please suggest me by Twilio